# Datagrams approach, where is the forwarding table is stored?(in the packet to be sent or the switches)?

Tags: networking, forwarding, switching

In computer networks, Switching and Forwarding, Datagrams approach, where is the forwarding table is stored?(in the packet to be sent or the switches)?

Answer (score 0):

It's usually in a routing table internal to the switch.

Some protocols allow the packets itself to specify the routing via [source routing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_routing) .IP datagrams provides support this, in which case the datagrams carries information on where to route the IP packet. An IP router would use that information carried in the packet to forward the packet, but it'd use internal tables for doing the transmissions on a lower layer (e.g. ethernet)